# Magento 2.1.8 Renaming image url after import or save

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento-2.1.8

Is there anyone that knows a way of renaming product images after import or at save, from the original to the product's url + .jpg? e.g. if the product url is black-backpack.html and the original name of the product image is backpack-b.jpg, then I would somehow like the image to be renamed black-backpack.jpg a.k.a. the url + .jpg

Since I am new to magento 2 programming I would appreciate to get step by step instructions on any solution that you would like to share.

I am using magento 2.1.8 CE

I would really appreciate any comments and solutions to this issue.

/Sabina